# Azure PowerShell Virtual Machine alert email function

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Just wondering if anyone has any PowerShell code snippets which can ping an email informing the user when their Virtual Machine starts and deallocates through an automated Run Book?

I have all the rest, but just wanted to add the email code feature to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a giant gallery of Azure Automation runbooks created by Microsoft and the community.  You can read about Runbook and Module Galleries for Azure Automation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery).  The actual gallery items can be found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f[0].Type=RootCategory&f[0].Value=WindowsAzure&f[1].Type=SubCategory&f[1].Value=WindowsAzure_automation&f[1].Text=Automation).

Answer (score 3):

> Just wondering if anyone has any PowerShell code snippets which can
>   ping an email informing the user when their Virtual Machine starts and
>   deallocates through an automated Run Book?

If you want to use runbook to send email, we should have a **SMTP server** first.

Then we can use PowerShell command to do it:

`Send-MailMessage`

More information about `Send-MailMessage`, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1).

Another way, we can use **Azure SendGrid Service** to send mails, here is the powershell script:

```
$Username ="YourUserName"

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "AddYourPasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password

$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net"

$EmailFrom = "No-reply@azureadmin.com"

[string[]]$EmailTo = "AddToEmailAddressessHere. To add multiple use comma separated values."
$Subject = "Sending sample email using SendGrid Azure and PowerShell"

$Body = "This is sample email sent using Sendgrid account create on Microsoft Azure. The script written is easy to use."

Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $credential -Usessl -Port 587 -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml
Write-Output "Email sent succesfully."
```

About create Azure sendgrid service, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email).

Also we can use **Azure activity log alerts** to send mail to you, more information about create activity log alerts, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Sorry for the reply. Yes that'll be fine, thank you :) Happy New Year as well.

Comment: @user9118621 Happy New Year :)